# PHP bind_param doesn't work in MySQli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this error:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object 
>   in /home/ccraft50/public_html/C-Blog/InsertDataPosts.php on line 15

---

```
   <?php
$servername2 = "localhost";
$username2 = "My DB";
$password2 = "My Pass";
$dbname2 = "My DB";
// Create connection
$dbconn2 = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2, $dbname2);
// Check connection
if ($dbconn2->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbconn2->connect_error);
 } 
$insIndexData = $dbconn2->prepare("INSERT INTO " . str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|.$+-%#@!~&;\',=~` '), "_", $_POST['filename']) . "_Index (SubjectName, IndexData) VALUES (?, ?)");

$str_prot_index = array('<script>', '</script>', '<?php', '?>', '<html', '</html>', '<body', '</body>', '<head', '</head>', '<pre', '</pre>', '<div', '</div>');
$insIndexData->bind_param('ss', $_POST['filename'], str_replace($str_prot_index, '', $_POST['comment']));
$insIndexData->execute();
$insIndexData->close();

if($dbconn2->prepare($insIndexData)) {
        echo "Successfuly Insert data for index!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $dbconn2->error;
}

$dbconn2->close();
?>
```

Comment: I'd guess that your query has failed; echo it out to see what it looks like - you're doing a lot of processing to make sure that the table name is right, and I suspect something is going wrong.

Comment: The $insIndexData?

Comment: If you really must go this way (I doubt it, see the answer below), you should use a white-list instead of a blacklist of characters for your table name; a hacker trying to access your system can probably think of more characters than you can blacklist.

Comment: okay I will try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a database wrong way.

A database have to consist of tables, each holding *multiple* rows. While you apparently want to create a distinct table for each file. Instead, you have to **store all your files in a single table**, adding a filename as a field, not a table name.

```
$stmt = $dbconn2->prepare("INSERT INTO files (SubjectName, IndexData) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['filename'], $_POST['comment']);
$stmt->execute();
echo "Successfuly Insert data for index!";
```

Note that the second part of code which is preparing the same query in a second time makes no sense. To test whether the insert were successful or not, you have to add this line **before** `new mysqli(`:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

And it will throw an error if insert fails.

Comment: It was just a typo

Comment: Thank very much for helping me! :)

Comment: Sorry @Your Common Sense I accidentally post/ask my old subject :D

Comment: It is not a subject that is old but approach you are still using. There is absolutely no sense in creating that lot of tables. You should change your code to make it use only ONE table.

Comment: Ex: SELECT * FROM Files WHERE TBL_NAME = TBL_NAME;

Comment: Yes, something like this

Answer (score -1):

Your prepare is failing. Try to add some testing to make sure its preparing correctly. After you `->prepare`

```
if($insIndexData !== false)
{
    etc...
```

Comment: This kind of code makes no sense. **it won't** make this code work

Comment: When the prepare fails it returns a `false`. So yes it can work if that was the problem. I always test the return of the prepare in my code before continuing.

Comment: Errors have to be not "worked around". They have to be revealed and **fixed.**

Comment: Testing is not a work around. Can you give a reason this will not reveal the error?

Comment: Can you give a reason it will?

Comment: The error above he gave shows that he's attempting to prepare a faulty statement. If he caught that error by testing it he would most likely see that his problem is NOT is his bind_param line like he originally assumed.